# JavaScript: How to interpret a variation of the `Math.floor(Math.random)` method?

Tags: javascript, math, random, integer

It seems that `Math.random()*3|0` equates to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`, which is the version I'm familiar with. While I have no problem understanding the step-by-step process of how the latter generates integers 0, 1, and 2, the structure of the former stumps me. It may well be an idiomatic variation of the more roundabout `Math.floor` method.

Is it possible to express the following two snippets of code in `x|y` style instead and produce the same results? If so, could you break down how it works?

---

```
1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) // yielding 1-100 (inclusive)

190 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) // yielding 190-255 (inclusive)
```

Comment: `num | 0` is basically the same as `Math.floor(num)`

Answer (score 2):

| is the Bitwise Or operator in javascript. 
The Bitwise Or operator returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.
x | 0 is x, for any x

The bitwise operator works only for integers, so javascript converts the float into an integer. 
Thus 1.5 | 0 becomes 1.

Your expressions can be rewritten as

```
1 + (Math.random() * 100 | 0)

190 + (Math.random() * 66 | 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

| is a bitwise OR operator. It returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.

You can easily change your methods into the following:

```
1 + Math.random()*100|0

190 + Math.random()*66|0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears, according to the EMCAScript Specification, that when a bit-wise operator is applied to a number it is converted to an Int32 value. This would explain the behavior. 
Link: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10

"The production A : A @ B, where @ is one of the bitwise operators in the productions above, is evaluated as follows:

Let lref be the result of evaluating A.
Let lval be GetValue(lref).
Let rref be the result of evaluating B.
Let rval be GetValue(rref).
Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
Let rnum be ToInt32(rval).
Return the result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result is a signed 32 bit integer. "